# How to solve quadratic equation problem having a prepositional logic?

Tags: quadratics

> When $\alpha,\beta$ are roots of $x^2+bx+c=0$, Find the equation whose roots are $p$ and $q$ where, $p=\alpha +\beta^2,\,q=\beta+\alpha^2$. Also  when  $\alpha,\beta$ are imaginary show that,  $b=-1\,$if and only if $p,q$ are real.

So far I have found the required equation as (say g(x)); $$g(x)=x^2-(b^2-b-2c)x+(b^2+c^2+c+3bc)=0$$

For the second part, it is given that $\alpha,\beta$ are imaginary. i.e $b^2-4c<0$

First I assumed $b=-1$ then $$\Delta g(x)=(b^2-b-2c)^2-4(b^2+c^2+c+3bc) =0$$ 
which gives $p,q$ are real (also coincidental)

Then I assumed $p,q$ are real which gives,
$$\Delta g(x)\geq0$$
$$(b^2-b-2c)^2\geq4(b^2+c^2+c+3bc)$$

after few simplifications I ended up with,
$$(b^2-4c)(b+1)^2-4b^2(b+1)\geq0$$

How can I say that $b=-1$ at this stage, Do I need to simplify this further? Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: I think there's an error in  $g(x)$: the constant term should be $\;\color{red}-b^{\color{red}3}+c+c^2+3bc$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in your  polynomial $g(x)$: indeed

- $ p+q=\alpha+\beta+\alpha^2+\beta^2=-b+(-b)^2-2c=b^2-b-2c$,
- $pq=\alpha^3+\beta^3+\alpha\beta+\alpha^2\beta^2=(\alpha+\beta)^3-3\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)+\alpha\beta+\alpha^2\beta^2=-b^3+3bc+c+c^2$,

so $\qquad\qquad g(x)=x^2-(b^2-b-2c)x-b^3+3bc+c+c^2$.

Now $p$ and $q$ are real if and only if $\;(b^2-b-2c)^2+4(b^3-3bc-c-c^2)\ge 0$.
Let's factorise the l.h.s.:
\begin{align}
(b^2-b&-2c)^2+4(b^3-3bc-c-c^2)\\
&=(b^2-b)^2-4(b^2-b)c+4c^2+4(b^3-3bc-c-c^2)\\
&=(b^2-b)^2+4b^3+4c(b-b^2+c-3b-1-c)=b^2(b+1)^2-4c(b+1)^2\\&=(b+1)^2(b^2-4c)\ge 0.
\end{align}
If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are imaginary, $b^2-4c<0$ so the only possibility for $(b+1)^2(b^2-4c)$ to be $\ge 0$ is that 
$$(b+1)^2=0.$$